# What's [TCP ACKed unseen segment] & etc in Wireshark?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark, scp

[image]

I've transfer a data via SCP and get some messages in picture above (in black color).What relation about these messages (TCP ACKed...,TCP Zerowindow and TCP Prev...). 
Thank you very much and sorry about language from network newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACK` on a `TCP` packet gives the sequence number the **other machine** shall use next:

```
SYN (seq=1)            ->  received
recived                <-  SYN, ACK (seq=101, ack=2)
"hi" (seq=2, ack=102)  ->  received 2 bytes
received               <-  ACK (seq=102, ack=4)
recived 2 bytes        <-  "ho" (seq=103, ack=4)
```

i.e. `ACK` is sent on every packet to the other machine saying:  "The next sequence number i expect from you is **this number**".

`ACK`s are never increased if part of data was never seen.  Has "hi" not been received in the above example (by network congestion for example) the right side will reject all packets until a packet with seq=2 is received.  `TCP` deals with that internally by repeating the seq=2 packet.

Your `wireshark` log suggests that some packet was not seen by it.  The packet might have goen through the network normally (and probably it did, otherwise it would have been repeated) but `wireshark` did not capture it.  That is a completely possible scenario, in busy networks `wireshark` often fails to capture every packet.